# How to iterate array without for in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have `RDD[(BreezeMatrix[Double], Array[Int])]` and i want to delete the columns of the `Matrix` that are in the `array`.

E.g if `Array[1, 3, 4]`, I want to delete 1, 3, 4 columns from the `Matrix`.

My code is:

```
 val  viol = rdd.map(x =>  for (p <- x._2) {val c = x._1.delete(p, Axis._0)})
```

But for start i get `Unit` as return type, even if i return the matrix.
Additionally, i was wondering if there is a more functional way to do it in scala.

Comment: Probably you are getting the `Unit` because `x._1.delete(...)` does return it. Anyhow let me remind you that may not be a good idea to update an object while you are iterating it.

Comment: Just out of my head since I don't have much time atm: I think you could duplicate the matrix and use 'filter' to exclude the rows in your array. Might also be necessary to use 'zipWithIndex' to remember which row has which index and finally use a map-function to remove the indices again before returning the final matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More functional way is to iterate over array of indexes to delete with accumulating state between iteration steps. You can use *foldLeft* for this purpose. *foldLeft* works over collection of elements, in your case the array of indexes to delete:

```
rdd.map{
  case (matrix, toDelete) => 
    toDelete.foldLeft(matrix){case (acc, index) => acc.delete(index, Axis._0)}
}
```